# Polymer website tutorial not running | undefined is not a function

Tags: polymer

I'm new to polymer and I started to follow this easy first tutorial on the official website
http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/tutorial/step-1.html

all was very easy but nothing was working. Or better, I have only one problem. When I tap on the top menu ("All or favourite") nothing changes and I get this error on console

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function Element.js:104
Selected: favorites (index):65
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function Element.js:104
Exception caught during observer callback: TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at b.classList (http://127.0.0.1/polymer/components/platform/platform.js:13:20941)
    at Polymer.selectedIndexChanged     (data:text/javascript;base64,CgogIFBvbHltZXIoJ3BhcGVyLXRhYnMnLCB7CiAgICAKICA…cG9uZW50cy9wYXBlci10YWJzL3BhcGVyLXRhYnMuaHRtbC9wYXBlci10YWJzLmpzCg==:45:26)
    at e.invokeMethod (http://127.0.0.1/polymer/components/polymer/polymer.js:12:10242)
    at e.notifyPropertyChanges     (http://127.0.0.1/polymer/components/polymer/polymer.js:12:9459)
    at Object.Observer.report_ (http://127.0.0.1/polymer/components/platform/platform.js:12:12892)
    at Object.createObject.check_ (http://127.0.0.1/polymer/components/platform/platform.js:12:18346)
    at Object.global.Platform.performMicrotaskCheckpoint (http://127.0.0.1/polymer/components/platform/platform.js:12:13792)
    at http://127.0.0.1/polymer/components/platform/platform.js:16:24471
    at Object.c [as callback_] (http://127.0.0.1/polymer/components/platform/platform.js:15:9571)
    at Array.c (http://127.0.0.1/polymer/components/platform/platform.js:12:27047)
```

I thought I did something wrong so I downloaded the example file but I have downloaded the source of the example and I still get the same errors.
Any help? =)

Thx everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some components in the tutorial repo were out of sync. If you pull the updated repo, these errors should go away.

Answer (score 0):

Updating chrome to version 35 or use [Chrome Beta](http://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/beta.html)

It errors on my linux box which has *Chrome Version 34.0.1847.137*.

It works on windows7 with *Chrome 35.0.1916.153m*

Comment: Hopefully the user has the same version

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.This is the error report https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-tutorial/issues/3

And this is where you can find the answer
https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-tutorial
It worked for me :)